# Standard deviation in normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

A manufacturer uses a machine to make metal rods.The diameter of the rods follow a normal distribution with a mean of 1cm and a standard deviation of 0.02cm

If the standard deviation of the diameters of the rods produced in the process can be adjusted,what should the new standard deviation be so that 90% of the rods produced will have diameters between 0.98cm and 1.02cm

My working is

$ X~(1,σ^2)$

$p(0.98-1/σ < Z < 1.02-1/σ)=0.90$

$P(-0.02/σ < Z < 0.02/σ)= (0.90-0.5)$
$P(-0.02/σ < Z < 0.02/σ)= (0.4)$

FROM THE TABLE

$P(-0.02/σ < Z < 0.02/σ)= (1.28)$

I'm stuck after that...help pls

Comment: From tables, we want $\frac{0.02}{\sigma}\approx 1.645$. This is because in the standard normal, we have probability $0.05$ of being in the right tail $\gt 1.645$, and probability $0.05$ of being in the left tail $\lt -1.645$.

Comment: Oh thank you so much!, now i do understand

Comment: You are welcome. In the ame way, the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$, that is, $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ counts the number of ways $k$ successes and $n-k$ failures could occur. In the case we have been discussing, the number of ways is $\binom{4}{2}$, which is $\frac{4!}{2!2!}$, which is $6$. But it was just as easy to give a complete list and count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a minor simplification mistake. With $X\sim N(1,\sigma^2)$
$$
0.9=Pr(0.98<X\leq 1.02)=Pr\left(\frac{0.98-1}{\sigma}<\frac{X-1}{\sigma}\leq\frac{1.02-1}{\sigma}\right)=Pr\left(\frac{-0.02}\sigma<Z\leq\frac{0.02}{\sigma}\right)
$$
where $Z=(X-1)/\sigma$ has a standard normal distribution, the CDF of which we denote by $\Phi$. Then,
$$
0.9=\Phi(0.02/\sigma)-\Phi(-0.02/\sigma)=\Phi(0.02/\sigma)-(1-\Phi(0.02/\sigma))=2\Phi(0.02/\sigma)-1
$$
so that
$$
\Phi(0.02/\sigma)=0.95.
$$
Now look up $0.02/\sigma$ from a table.